# My read message page shows multiple messages instead of one PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, chat

I have made a  private message system in PHP. 
It kinda works, the write, send, read and reply works.

But there is one problem. If i press on a specific message that i want to read in my Inbox or Outbox, (dosent matter which), my page which should show just the specific message i press on, shows all messages in that inbox/outbox. It looks like this on my page ->

*From:testing@l.seSubject:hello Message:Testing this.. From:testing@l.se 
 Subject:hello Message: test From:testing@l.seSubject:hej Message: skicka 
:Reply*

As you all can se, its all messages in a row. Edit: It messages that belongs to the right user. So its not messages that belongs to a diffrent user.

The sql for my messages are

```
id int(11) AI PK 
from_user varchar(45) 
to_user varchar(45) 
subject varchar(400) 
message text 
date date 
read tinyint(4)
```

I am fairly sure that my error should be somewhere here in

### read.inc.php

```
<?php 

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user = '$user'";

     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

     $stmt->execute();

     ?>

     <?php

     if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

         echo "<table";
         echo "<tr>";

        while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $id = $rows['id'];
            $to_user = $rows['to_user'];
            echo "<td>";
     ?>
     <?php
        echo "<td>From:";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "".$from = $rows['from_user']."";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "Subject:";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "".$subject = $rows['subject']."";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "Message:";    
        echo "<td>";
        echo "".$message = $rows['message']."";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   

        }

         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td colspan='2'><a href='messages.php?
      id=compose&mid=$id&subject=RE:$subject&to=$from'>Reply Message</a>
       </td>";
         echo "</tr>";
         echo "</table>";

  if ($to_user==$user) {

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `private_messages` SET `read`=1 WHERE 
  `id`=id");

        $a = 1;
        $stmt->bindParam(':1',$a);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);

        } 

     } else {
        echo "You cant see the conversation..";
     }

?>
```

I will also paste inbox and outbox if somone feels to look there to.

### This is outbox.inc.php

```
    <?php
$user = $_SESSION[ 'username' ];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE from_user = '$user'";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );


$stmt->execute();

?>
<?php

if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {

    ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>to: </td>";
    echo "<td>subject: </td>";
    echo "<td>Date: </td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ( $rows = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
        $id = $rows[ 'id' ];
        ?>
    <?php
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $from = $rows[ 'to_user' ] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='messages.php?id=read&mid=$id'>" . $subject = $rows[ 
   'subject' ] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $date = $rows[ 'date' ] . "</td>";
    echo "<tr>";

    }
    }
    else {

        echo "<table> <tr align='left'> <td> </td> <td>to_user: </td><td> 
  Subject: </td><td>Date: </td></tr><tr><th colspan='4'> You did not send a 
   message </th></tr></table>";

    }

    echo "</table>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And last my

### inbox.inc.php

```
    <?php
$user = $_SESSION[ 'username' ];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user = '$user'";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

$stmt->bindValue( ':to_user', $_SESSION[ 'username' ], PDO::PARAM_INT );

$stmt->execute();


?>
<?php

if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {

    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>from_user: </td>";
        echo "<td>subject: </td>";
        echo "<td>Date: </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        // om stmt är större än noll då finns de poster gör då detta
        // skriv ut posterna med en while loop
        while ( $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $rows['id'];

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp; </td>";
            echo "<td>" . $from = $rows[ 'from_user' ] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='messages.php?id=read&mid=$id'>" . $subject = 
           $rows[ 'subject'] . "</a></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $date = $rows[ 'date' ] . "</td>";
            echo "<tr>";

        }
        } else {

            echo "<table> <tr align='left'> <td> </td> <td>from_user: </td>
     <td> Subject: </td><td>Date: </td></tr><tr><th colspan='4'> You did not 
     recive a message </th></tr></table>";

        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Lots of code here, sorry for that.

/best regards Robert

Comment: You're using the same query for all your files which is (fetch all messages for a given user_id) ideally when viewing a message you should be getting a message_id via $_GET make sure it belongs to the user attempting to view it by comparing it to logged-in user & select only the desired message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following in your `read.inc.php`, which fetches all messages for a given user:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user = '$user'";`
```

To only get the message that you clicked on in your inbox you should use a query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to_user = '$user' AND id = $mid LIMIT 1";
```

(where `$mid` is the variable you get from `$_GET['mid']` in your query string).

You won't need the loop then, since you only fetch one row.

Please be aware that using variables in the query like this (especially when transmitted via query string) is VERY BAD and can/will lead to SQL injection attacks. Use bound variables (either with bindParam/bindVariable or in execute) like you did in `inbox.inc.php`!

Comment: Ah know it works, im gonna thnk more on security from now on.

Comment: So i have this new problem now. Im asking you  here first instead of making a new post. Its the same code as above, but now its the outbox. My code to view what messages i had send in the outbox worked fine. But now when i go to my outbox and press on a message there all i see is  my error  "You cant see the conversation..";  So the problem for that are in read and outbox. I tried to do the same thing with `$_Get['mid']` there to. But i dont get it to work.

Comment: The query in read.inc.php checks for to_user = $user, but if it's a sent message it should check for from_user = $user, I guess. For a start, you could just remove the `to_user = "$user" AND ` part of the query and see if it works with id only. But you should think about security after it works, because everyone can read every message then with just the id by starting with mid=1 and counting upwards. Maybe use `uuid` instead of a numeric id for user-facing code (this is just an added measure, not instead of proper security).